# Xamarin build-times extremely slow

Tags: xamarin, build, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I have developed several (experimental and prototype) iOS apps using Xamarin and the new Visual Studio for Mac OS and the build-times intermittently take about 5-10 minutes on average. When starting a new project, build-times are fine. After a few changes in the source code while working on my apps (no specific changes). For no reason, build times start increasing to 5-10 minutes. I've tried all possible build-options (linking, no linking, SDK versions, new consigning certificate, etc..).

Upon investigation with the Activities-app (Mac OS, Sierra) i find that the "codesign" process is taking up 110% CPU and runs for as long as the build takes to complete.

Does anyone have any experience with this problem?

Comment: One trick I use to make building faster is to right click on the solution and choose configuration manager, there you can choose what to build and when , often by default it selects all projects and all platforms , when you need is that to build only iOS when you set iOS as a startup project and to build only Android when you set Android as the startup project .

Comment: Builds in iOS are generally slow in xamarin. If you are creating crossplatform app and using forms - I would suggest to use android for quick build/test process.

Comment: Can you please add a diagnostic build output to your post so we can see where it's bottlenecking?

Comment: The problem is this: code signing process takes forever. So i don't think my build-log has anything to do with it. Running the application with the Simulator as a target, build/deployment times are good.

[![Schermafbeelding 2016-12-07 om 14.00.54.png](https://s18.postimg.org/rovd9te49/Schermafbeelding_2016_12_07_om_14_00_54.png)](https://postimg.org/image/4nes42egl/)

Comment: `codesign` is invoked by a MSBuild `Task/Target` when you are building. Thus a diagnostic build output would give us insight as to which `Task/Target` and then potentially finding the culprit.

Comment: @JonDouglas could you help me get those diagnostics? I would like to provide them. My project on iOS simulator builds fine, however, on the device it's painfully slow.

Comment: @nmdias https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27515/how-to-obtain-diagnostic-build-logs (XS) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx (VS)

Answer (score 8):

I have the same issue

**First Try** close Visual Studio then delete bin , obj from your project , finally start visual Build and Run

**Second Try**  make sure you build in real device sometimes emulator cause trouble , how you make sure , if build success but deploy stuck many times

Comment: Excellent advice, deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders from all the projects in my solution fixed the slow build issue right away.

Comment: I second that! My VS was stalling at the deployment phase!

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this, this did not work for me in the first build, but worked for every build after.

Comment: But what is the actual reason? What is happened when deleting bin and obj from project?

Comment: Are you made ? Should we close and run visual studio everytime ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, **after wiping my PC and completely re-installing Windows 10, my build speeds increased by 2x**.

Clean builds that used to take 2:20 minutes now only take 1:20 minutes, and incremental builds that used to take 40 seconds now only take 17 seconds.

Doing an incremental build + deploying to device used to take around 4 minutes. Now it takes only 55 seconds!

I'm not sure what was leading to this awful experience, but I'm glad it's not so terrible anymore (still slow though).

Comment: I agree it's not the most ideal solution (probably the least ideal solution), however when you're completely out of options even the least ideal solution is useful. I tried changing every single build option, no luck. Turning off Windows Search indexer also seemed to help things.

Comment: @LucaZiegler a process that solves the problem is, by definition, a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your *.Android project => "Properties" => "Android Options" and set the following options:

- Dex compiler: **dx**
- Linking: **None**

This gives me a fast build speed